# Randomness in quantum phenomena

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, polarization

I'm reading "Six Quantum Pieces" as a introduction to quantum mechanics.
Assuming that we have two functions. One that determine the probability for a photon to be transmitted, and other the probability for it to be reflected:
$$
P_{t} = cos^{2}(\alpha)\\
P_{r} = sin^{2}(\alpha)
$$
Based on the preposition that the behaviour of a photon is unpredictable when beamed into a polarizer... Isn't $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2} \text{ or } \alpha = 0$ a counter example for that?

Sorry if it's a stupid question... But, at the moment, I can't agree with that sentence, because when $\alpha = 0$ I can assume that it's direction of oscillation is going to be the same as the polarizer, and $cos^{2}(0) = 1$ so the probability will be 100%!!!

Sorry again for the newbie question! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct and the ideas you have discovered generalise to many different quantum systems.

For a general polarizer orientation the experimental result of measuring transmit/reflect will be uncertain and can only be specified as probabilities of the different outcomes.

If the photon has been prepared in a given polarization and we "measure" that orientation by aligning out filter with the photons polarization then we do get a certain outcome.

It is tempting at this point to think quantum mechanics is not so weird and different from normal classical physics where we can just think of particles having definite properties that we can measure.

But when we say that quantum mechanics is uncertain or non deterministic we mean that however we prepare a particle there will always be *some* experiment on the particle which we cannot predict with certainty. In this case any rotation away from the polarization direction results in uncertainty.

Comment: Really nice answer. Thanks alot... the thing is... if we're thinking in terms of photons, the probability is going to be in the results of its polarization... we're never going to be able get a 100% probability for transimssion or reflection if we don't align it oscilation with the same angle as the polarizer... Got it... crazy stuff there haha